# FFmpeg - H264 encoder could not find a valid device and can't configure encoder

Tags: c, ffmpeg, h.264

I am trying to encode using the H264 encoder, but when I do, I get the following error:

```
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x55682d2416c0] Could not find a valid device
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x55682d2416c0] can't configure encoder
```

I made sure that I enabled the encoder when I configured FFmpeg. When I run the command `ffmpeg -codecs` I see that the H264 codec is listed as an encoder:

```
DEV.LS h264    H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
(decoders: h264 h264_v4l2m2m )
(encoders: libx264 libx264rgb h264_v4l2m2m h264_vaapi )
```

The source video's video codec is H264 so I am not sure why I am not able to encode with H264 when there is both a decoder and encoder for it. Even when I run `avcodec_find_encoder_by_name` to find the `libx264` encoder, it isn't able to.

This is the chunk of code where it fails:

```
codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
if (!codec) {
    printf("[ERROR] Failed to find video output codec\n");
    return -1;
}
outputCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
if (!outputCodecContext) {
    printf("[ERROR] Failed to allocate memory for video output codec context\n");
    return -1;
}
av_opt_set(outputCodecContext->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);
outputCodecContext->bit_rate = inputCodecContext->bit_rate;
outputCodecContext->width = inputCodecContext->width;
outputCodecContext->height = inputCodecContext->height;
outputCodecContext->time_base = (AVRational){1, 60};
outputCodecContext->framerate = (AVRational){60, 1};
outputCodecContext->pix_fmt = inputCodecContext->pix_fmt;
outputCodecContext->extradata = inputCodecContext->extradata;
outputCodecContext->extradata_size = inputCodecContext->extradata_size;

// This if statement fails as a result of the encoder error
if (avcodec_open2(outputCodecContext, codec, NULL) < 0) {
    printf("[ERROR] Failed to open video output codec\n");
    return -1;
}
return 0;
```

When I encode with H264 using the `ffmpeg` command, I don't receive any of these errors. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, I kept forgetting to call `make` and `make install` (I'm on Ubuntu) after I used the command `./configure --enable-shared --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl`. This removed the error I was receiving and my code was able to find the `libx264` encoder.

Comment: I do have --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-shared

but 
av_opt_set(codec_ctx->priv_data, "crf", "12", 0);
av_opt_set(codec_ctx->priv_data, "profile", "main", 0);
av_opt_set(codec_ctx->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);

with the same error: Option not found

and avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, codec, nullptr); fails with error:
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x7fffa8fb3f80] Could not find a valid device
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x7fffa8fb3f80] can't configure encoder

but if I use the ffmpeg application it works

Any idea how to do this from c++?